# React Native APK installed but not showing on mobile

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I build an android APK installer using command npx react-native run-android --variant=release on windows, I get the apk at build > outputs > apk > release app-release.apk.

after installing on my mobile android device the app is not showing or unable to open.
Pls help, my react-native version is 0.66.3

[image]

Comment: It could be bug with system. Try to open app through home screen.